# IE11 CSS Select list word wrap

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer-11, word-wrap

Using ASP.NET I'm trying to build a `ListBox` in which each option's text wraps to the next line, in case the line is longer than the listbox's width, only using CSS.

Using the `word-wrap: break-word` CSS property is sufficient to get this working in Chrome, however, this does not work for IE11.

I've searched around and found various alternatives for similar problems, which included some combination of the following properties:

```
-ms-word-wrap: break-word; 
word-wrap: break-word; 
word-break: break-all; 
white-space: pre-wrap; 
width: 100%;
```

None of which seem to work for me.

Am I missing something? Or does IE11 simply not support this and do I need to resort to an external plugin?

Comment: IE will support them http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Answer (score -1):

Word wrap is supported by IE.

`word-wrap` is a CSS3 element and is supported by IE9 +, but for IE8 you will need to use the prefix `-ms-` on it.

`-ms-word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I already tried that. The problem here is that it doesn't work inside a `ListBox` control.